# vue-chartjs graph in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graph, vuejs3

I use the vue-chartjs and chart.js libraries to create graphics, but with the switch to vue 3, the way I code graphics has totally changed. Here is my old code.

```
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs';

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  watch: {
    'chartData.labels': function () {
      this.$data._chart.update();
    },
    'chartData.datasets': function () {
      this.$data._chart.update();
    },
  },
  props: {
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
    barClick: {
      type: Function,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  methods: {
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
    if (this.barClick) {
      this.$refs.canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const element = this.$data._chart.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];
        if (element) this.barClick(element);
      });
    }
  },
};
```

then, in my vue file, I import the graph

`import TicketReport from '../components/BarChart';`

and I define it

```
components: {
  TicketReport,
  ...
}
```

then I use it like this

```
<div v-if="chart.display" style="position: relative;">
          <ticket-report
            style="margin-top:10px;"
            height="600px"
            ref="chart"
            :chart-data="chart.data"
            :options="chart.options"
            :bar-click="barClicked"
          />
          <v-btn
            class="reset-legend"
            v-show="external.resetLegend"
            absolute
            fab
            small
            top
            left
            dark
            color="grey darken-3"
            @click="resetLegend"
          >
            <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </div>
```

Now, I want to use the new version here https://vue-chartjs.org/migration-guides/#changing-the-creation-of-charts but I'd like to define the BarChart component in a second view file and only call it in the view file of my web page (as this BarChart is reused in different files).

Can you help me?